# how to extract values of a response body of a collection runner

Tags: json, postman

I've run my code in postman windows environment and i didnt know how to save specific values of response body but i find the following code to save the whole response body using the following code in Test part:

```
reponseBodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.test("Response Body Printout= (" + responseBody
 + ")", function () {
});
```

Now, I've following similar output

```
"testPassFailCounts": {
"Response Body Printout= ({\"BirthDate\":12345678,\"DeathDate\":\"14000616\",\"DeathStatus\":0})": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
                },
  "Response Body Printout= ({\"BirthDate\":87654321,\"DeathDate\":\"13560115\",\"DeathStatus\":1)": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
    .....
                },
```

How may I extract variables such as deathStatus and DeathDate and output in a file from my response body file? or from the first input file ?
Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

File `google-services.json` is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.